# Why did the translators add the words "that they may be healed" to James 5 v 16

Tags: james, healing

In my Interlinear bible, the words 'ye may be healed' come under one Greek word iaomai (Strongs No G2390) to cure, heal, make whole. For some, adding the word may introduces some doubt, ie may or may not be healed. Why did the translators add these words to to this verse and not to any others were the word healed is used.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Is this a question about Greek grammar, or about English grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple grammatical question that is resolved by understanding how the Greek works.

Greek is a highly inflected language, especially the verbs.  The verb in question here is: ἰάομαι (iaomai) = "I heal", in its lexical form; however, in James 5:16 it occurs in the form ἰαθῆτε (iathēte) = Verb - Aorist Subjunctive Passive - 2nd Person Plural; and so must be translated, "you [plural] may be healed".

Because of the versatility and inflection in the Greek verbs, pronouns are only rarely needed because the verb contains all that is required to convey the meaning.  This is a perfect example where the pronouns have not been used but the sense is perfectly clear.

Lastly, note that the "mood" of the verb is "subjunctive" and the "voice" is "passive", that is why it must be translated with a "may" and that the action is not done by the subject.

Your translation is quite valid and every other version will show something similar.

Comment: Thank you, dose the word 'may' mean you will be healed or does it have an element of doubt in it?

Comment: @Stephen - it is the English method we have of expressing the subjunctive mood.  It does NOT mean that a person "might" be healed, it expresses the idea that under these circumstances, the way is provided for healing.

Answer (score 1):

Because this seems to have been the standard way of formulating [expressions of this type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) in [early modern English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English). The presence of the [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)) *that* modifies the [auxiliary verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) usually responsible for constructing the [future tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense), resulting in an(other) tense altogether, called *conjunctive* or *subjunctive*. (For more information, feel free to consult our two sister sites, [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) and [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com)). Thus, within the traditional [King James version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version), the [statistical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_distribution) is as follows:

- **that you/ye may** appears **92** times,
- **that you/ye might** appears **27** times,
- **that you/ye be** appears **eleven** times,
- **that you/ye will** appears **seven** times.

Similarly for other pronouns:

- **that I may** appears **144** times,
- **that I will** appears **66** times,
- **that I might** appears **39** times,
- **that I be** appears **twice**.

---

- **that (s)he may** appears **103** times,
- **that (s)he might** appears **69** times,
- **that (s)he will** appears **twenty** times,
- **that (s)he be** appears **twice**.

---

- **that we may** appears **74** times,
- **that we might** appears **nineteen** times,
- **that we will** appears **six** times,
- **that we be** appears **twice**.

---

- **that they may** appears **155** times,
- **that they might** appears **66** times,
- **that they be** appears **ten** times,
- **that they will** appears **five** times.

It follows that, by and large, the most frequent auxiliary verbs, in descending order of preference, are:

- **may**, appearing (over) **568** times,
- **might**, appearing (over) **220** times,
- **will**, appearing (over) **104** times,
- **be**, appearing (over) **27** times.

(The above is for pronouns only; other auxiliaries are *shall, shalt,* and *should*, for which the interested reader is invited to construct their own tables, using a biblical software of their own choice; personally, I have employed [*Theophilos*](http://www.theophilos.com/download.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

Strongs No G2390 iaomai shows the lexicon (dictionary) spelling and meaning of a Greek word. When this word is used in James 5:16, it is spelled as [iathēte](https://biblehub.com/james/5-16.htm). That is its subjunctive form. The Greek subjunctive mood primarily refers to HYPOTHETICAL actions in the PRESENT or FUTURE. In English we use the subjunctive mainly when talking about events that are not certain to happen.

Further, hopōs iathēte (so that you may be healed) forms potential subjunctive purpose clause. It is not 100% definite but it has that potential. The focus is on the positive potential.

That is why it is translated as 'may be healed' in James 5:16. The translators translate the lexicon meaning of the word plus its subjunctive mood.

In https://biblehub.com/james/5-16.htm, 25 out of 27 versions translated as 'may be healed'. It is the overwhelming consensus.  Good News Translation has over-translated iathēte

> So then, confess your sins to one another and pray for one another, so that you **will be healed**. The prayer of a good person has a powerful effect.

Comment: Thank you Tony, can I ask,  how did you find out that in James 5:16 the word healed is spelled as iathete? Also, when you say the actions in the Present or Future,  but are they definite ? ie its going  to happen, or in this case 'that you may or may not be healed.

Comment: I made modification.